# ajax multiple images upload

Tags: ajax, image, uploader

I've been browsing the web trying to find a library that would allow me to do a few specific things for image upload but couldn't find exactly what I wanted and was wondering if anybody knew of such a library. I want to allow the user to:

upload multiple images at once
display the thumbnail for each image after it was uploaded
have a "description" field for each image
be able to re-sort the images after they've been uploaded

I found this one (http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-demo.html#demo4) which is pretty close to what I want, but it won't let me sort the uploaded images. Is there a way to easily tweak it to be able to do that?

or does anybody know of another image uploader plugin that would have all these features? (All of these features are kind of like what the facebook image uploader is like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kentor I have exactly what you want(I hope so)...
I found this a while ago, hope it's useful and serve's the purpose right.

Code: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Demos: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/